# Transaction gas problem

Tags: javascript, ethers.js, gas-price, gas-estimate, sendtransaction

I wanna send transaction and before that i wanna calculate the gas fee and input value as much as : finalAmount = value - gasFee

For doing this i get gas price from provider this way:

```
const gasP = _provider.getGasPrice()
```

And also estimate gas:

```
const estimateGas = await _signer.estimateGas(user.address)
```

I set the value this way:

```
 const fee = (await gasP).mul(estimateGas)

 const finalAmount = amount.sub(fee)
```

And thats my transaction function:

```
async function claim() {

    signer.sendTransaction({
      from: user,
      to: Receptient,
      
      gasPrice: gasP,
      gasLimit: ethers.utils.hexlify(100000),
      value: finalAmount,
    })
  }
```

But when i call the function, my MetaMask pops up and want to send transaction with this amount of fee:
0.00000411GoerliETH

And transaction fails with this amount fee.

How can i fix that? it looks estimate gas less than the amount which i need to send my transaction.

Answer (score 0):

```
const gasPrice = await _provider.getGasPrice();
```

Use the **getGasPrice** method provided by the **_provider** object to get the current gas price on the Ethereum network, and then use that gas price when sending your transaction.

Comment: Actually, i get it as 'gasP', but my transaction fails, i solved it by adding gas price manually , but i don't like this way i want to calculate gas fee from blockchain data.

Comment: getGasPrice should get the gas price from the network - do you get any errors?

Comment: No, when i call gas price, it get gas price from network for me, but the problem is when multiply gasPrice and and estimateGas together, this number can not cover transaction fee

Comment: I could be missing something but why gasprice x estimategas?

Comment: So how can i calculate & set enough gas for cover transaction fee? its wrong?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why you're using gasprice X estimate gas. I would just use const gasP = _provider.getGasPrice() instead of multiplying it. See what that returns.